# Weak convergence of simple functions implies strong convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, bochner-spaces

For each $n$, let $\{A_j^n\}_j$ be a disjoint partition of the interval $[0,1]$ such that as $n$ increases, the partition gets finer.

Suppose that we have
$$f_n(t) = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{jn}\chi_{A_j^n}(t)$$
where $a_{jn} \in V$ belongs to a Hilbert space $V \subset\subset H$. We have that $f_n$ is bounded uniformly in $L^\infty(0,T;V)$ so there is a subsequence that converges weak-* in that space.

Is there anyway to extract pointwise a.e. in $t$ convergence for $f_n$ (or a subsequence) or any sort of strong convergence in Bochner space? I thought that since $f_n$ is defined everywhere and is continuous a.e., and indeed is piecewise constant in time, we might gains something.

Comment: In the title you suggest you are assuming weak convergence but this appears nowhere in the question. Does something need to be changed?

Comment: The uniform bound I mentioned in the post implies weak (and weak-*) convergence for a subsequence for $f_n$

Comment: Right but you then ask to try to get a.e. in $t$ convergence for $f_n$. You have no hope of this because your assumption only applies something about convergence of a subsequence.

Comment: I agree but I did write (or a subsequence) in the last paragraph

Comment: If $V$ is infinite-dimensional, you can just take $f_n(t)=e_n$ for some orthonormal system $(e_n)$, which clearly has no convergent subsequence.

Comment: Please correct me if I understand something wrong but for $A_j$ to be the partition of $[0,1]$ with equal length $1/j$ and $a_j = j$, then $\displaystyle f_{n}(t) = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \cdot \chi_{A_j}(t)$ is not bounded.

Or you also assume that $f_n$ defined in your question is also uniformly bounded?

Comment: @CanTurkun Yes I am assuming that it is uniformly bounded.

Comment: @MaoWao But my $f_n$ is as in the post and not of that form

Comment: But $f_n$ is of that form. Take any sequences of partitions that gets finer and simply put $a_{jn}=e_n$ for all $j$.

Comment: You're right @MaoWao